# Animation of moon phases

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

Tell me how I should scale shadow mask to create an animation change of the phase of the moon, please?
As in the example in the upper right corner: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/lps/animations/lps.swf

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this quite easily using a Shape tween.

There are lots of tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 1):

The author dynamically draws in a mask MC ( beginFill(), lineTo() and curveTo() ) over a graphic shadow.